# Remove sequence of a specific character from the end of a string in Bash

Tags: bash, sed

**Input:**

```
i="Item1;Item2;Item3;;;;;;;;"
```

**Desired output:**

```
i="Item1;Item2;Item3"
```

How do I get rid of the last few semicolons?

I know this one way to do it using 'sed':

```
sed 's/;$//'
```

However, it only removes the last semicolon. Running it repeatedly doesn't seem practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/;*$//'
```

The main point here is to add the `*` quantifier (that means *zero or more*) after `;` to make the regex engine match zero or more semi-colons.

Synonymic `sed` commands can look like

```
sed 's/;;*$//'    # POSIX BRE "one ; and then zero or more ;s at the end of string"
sed 's/;\+$//'    # GNU sed POSIX BRE "one or more semi-colons at the end of string"
sed -E 's/;+$//'  # POSIX ERE "one or more semi-colons at the end of string"
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need external utilities for this.

```
$ input='Item1;Item2;Item3;;;;;;;;'
$ echo "${input%"${input##*[!;]}"}"
Item1;Item2;Item3
```

Or, using extended globs:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${input%%*(;)}"
Item1;Item2;Item3
```

Comment: You saved a fork or two, nice

Answer (score 0):

With a conditional jump (`t`) to label `a`:

```
i="Item1;Item2;Item3;;;;;;;;"
sed ':a; s/;$//; ta' <<< "$i"
```

> `t label`: If a `s///` has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last `t` or `T` command, then branch to label.